# How to use link_to inside select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I use link_to inside select_tag ? Something like this ...

```
<%= select_tag "test1","<option>#{link_to 'View Details', view_path(test)}</option><option>#{link_to 'Delete', delete_path(test)}</option><option>#{link_to 'Edit Details', edit_path(test)}</option>"%>
```

Any solution ?

Comment: why would you want that? basic html: links don't work inside drop-down boxes dude :)

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= select_tag "test1","<option value='#{view_path(test)}'>View Details</option><option value='#{delete_path(test)}'>Delete</option><option value='#{edit_path(test)}'>Edit Details</option>" ,:onchange => "window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')" %>
```

Comment: you questions should be more descriptive